# Writing a dictionay of lists to file and reading it back again (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a dictionary of lists, of different lengths.

An example:

```
{'Naldo': ['03bd0bf4', 'a2609621'], 
'Nino': ['03dc5b1f'], 
'Matty Daly': ['03e48abb']}
```

I'm wondering the best way to save and then re-read this dictionary from disk.

Many thanks.

Comment: use **json_dumps** then save as a json file. then read json file with **json_loads**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make your exercise with pickle.

```
import pickle

tomp_dic = {'Naldo': ['03bd0bf4', 'a2609621'], 
'Nino': ['03dc5b1f'], 
'Matty Daly': ['03e48abb']}

tomp_file = open('dic.pckl', 'wb')

pickle.dump(tomp_dic, tomp_file)

tomp_file.close()

tomp_new_file = open('dic.pckl','rb')

tomp_new_dic = pickle.load(tomp_new_file)

print (tomp_new_dic)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- save with json.dump

```py
import json
data = {'Naldo': ['03bd0bf4', 'a2609621'], 
'Nino': ['03dc5b1f'], 
'Matty Daly': ['03e48abb']}
with open("./data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

- load with json.load

```py
import json
with open("./data.json", "r") as f:
    data2 = json.load(data)
```